# Must all JNI methods be static?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Must all the methods that are native be also static??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, native methods can be non-`static`. In fact, [here is a JNI tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip23.html) which shows how to natively implement a non-`static` method.

Comment: Note: the tutorial page's formatting is a little messed up. If you wanted to follow it all the way through, then in the C code, `#include &ltStubPreamble.h>` needs to be `#include <StubPreamble.h>` and `#include &ltstdio.h>` needs to be `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: someone who can't work out how to demangle that C code shouldn't be allowed use JNI :-)